# Using GPUImage video into Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, gpuimage

I noticed that GPUImage is able to do fast video to OpenGL.
Does anyone know if it's possible to use GPUImage to send Video into Unity3D.

Any help is Greatly Appreciated it.

Edit:  I managed to get a RenderTexture from Unity into GPUImage as a textureID. Then converted into a textureInput of type GPUImageTextureInput.  movieFile is type GPUImageMovie.

```
// Setup GL texture from which we will be capturing images.
textureInput = [[GPUImageTextureInput alloc] initWithTexture:textureID size:frameSize];

// Pipe the texture directly to the movie Player.
[textureInput addTarget:movieFile];
```

Only problem is now I'm getting: 
        Incompatible pointer types sending 'GPUImageMovie *' to parameter of type       'GPUImageInput'

Question: What kind of input does GPUImageMovie take.

Comment: It has a texture output class, so if you can take in arbitrary textures into Unity (and create an OpenGL ES share group between the two rendering contexts), you should be able to do this. I know people were trying to do that.

Comment: Thanks Brad,  it's cool to get an answer from the author of GPUImage. I found a post at unity about this.  Do you think something like this will work with GPUImage's texture output class?

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/214310-Texture2D-CreateExternalTexture-and-Texture2D-UpdateExternalTexture?p=1451601#post1451601

Comment: To be Honest, I'm just learning IOS programming so this task is a bit daunting.  Does anyone have a simple example project that can play a movie using GPUImage and display it in Unity.